# simple question in vi editor on unix

Tags: unix, vim, vi

how could i add  some text like 'ABC' 
at the beginning of all the lines in vi editor?
this doesnot work!

```
%s/^/^ABC
```

i know this command is used for replacing text

```
%s/vggv/uggv/g
```

Answer (score 8):

You want:

```
:%s/^/ABC/g
```

That will put ABC in front of every line.

Don't forget the `:` in front

Comment: the `g` can be omitted as there will only be one start of line in a line. The ending `/` can also be omitted. Final command: `:%s/^/ABC`

Answer (score 8):

I really love the normal command for things like these:

```
:%normal IABC
```

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't `:%s/^/ABC/` work for you?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `:%s/^/ABC` will do the trick. Consider what `^` means. It is a logical construct, not an actual character in the file. Therefore, you're not really replacing it, so you don't have to use `^ABC`. In fact, as you've seen, `^` is treated as a string in that context.

If you wanted to skip lines that only contain whitespace, you could use `:v/^[:space:]*$/s/^/ABC`.

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/^/ABC/g
```

this will add ABC in front of every line in vi editor